# Обнаружение пересечение элемента с другими (svg)?

Tags: javascript, svg

Есть ли в svg какой то встроенный механизм обнаружения наложения одних элементов на  другие?

Например у меня есть dom элемент g. 
и мне надо выяснить с какими элементами этот элемент пересекается.
Каким образом такое лучше всего сделать?